# Appending div from its clone causes delayed duplication

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am cloning a div, change its image attributes and then appending it to the previous div. Everything works fine except when the new div is added which contains the new image source the previous one (from row 1, item 1) is being displayed for half second. This happens on each image on newly added divs. The first image from the initially loaded content is the one which is always loaded and then is replaced by the correct one but with some delay. The first set of images are loaded when the page loads (from code behind) and any new rows (as divs) are appearing as described above.

DIV

```
<div id="dvProducts">
    <asp:DataList ID="rptCustomers" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" CellPadding="0" CellSpacing="0" RepeatLayout="Table" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="wrapping">
                <div id="boxer">
                    <span class="Image" ><img src='<%# "images/topimages/" & Eval("Image")%>' alt="Mountain View" class="topimage"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:DataList>
</div>
```

Function:

```
customers.each(function () {
    var product = $(this);
    var tablex = $("#dvProducts div").eq(0).clone(true);
    $(".Image", tablex).find('img').attr('src', '/top3/images/topimages/' + product.find("Image").text());
    $("#dvProducts").append(tablex);
 });
```

Comment: can you set up a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Comment: @JNF I'm not sure how to set it up since the data comes from my database. I've never used fiddle before.